# How to add Unregisted Package in julia with continious Integration(gitlab-ci)

Tags: package, julia, gitlab-ci

I have created a package  `Xnumber`.And I have not registered it.

Now, I am creating another package(`SHbundle`) which uses the above package.Now in the julia REPL locally when I execute the following code:

```
julia> add "https://gitlab.com/vyush/Xnumber.jl.git"
julia> using Xnumber
```

It works fine locally and I can use the function but On pushing to SHbundle after adding Xnumber as dependency.
The pipeline script fail.
The command being executed is

```
- |
      julia --project=@. -e '
        using Pkg
        Pkg.build()
        Pkg.test(coverage=true)'
```

The error that I get is `ERROR: expected package Xnumber [fdc6275c] to be registered`. The package works fine locally but is giving error while executing the pipeline script.

I there any workaround for this without registering the packages.

The Links for these packages are: [Xnumber](https://gitlab.com/vyush/Xnumber.jl#master),[SHbundle](https://gitlab.com/vyush/SHbundle.jl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Remove the `/Manifest.toml` in your `.gitignore` file
2. Commit the `Manifest.toml` file after `julia> add "https://gitlab.com/vyush/Xnumber.jl.git"`
3. Add an extra step of `Pkg.instantiate()` in your pipeline

Answer (score 0):

The other answer with the Manifest files did not work for me, what worked is to manually add the unregistered package in the pipeline, e.g. with:

```
- name: instantiate environment
        run: |
            julia -e '
              using Pkg
              Pkg.add(url="https://xyz")
              Pkg.develop(PackageSpec(path=pwd()))'
```